# How to add whitespace to an RMarkdown document?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Is there a way to do it by adding latex code in the text or does the solution lie in (R)Markdown?

No sign of a solution here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html

At present I'm bodging a solution by adding my `monospace` signature to the bottom of the 1st page, to force the next section to start on page 2: https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/intro-spatial-rl.pdf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use latex inside your Rmd file. To have a page break, just add `\newpage`.

**example.Rmd**

```
Title
====================

This is a test Rmd document. 

\newpage

Second page
====================

This text is on the second page
```

You make a pdf using `render("example.Rmd", output_format='pdf_document')`

Hope it helps,

alex

Comment: Wow it's that simple. Having just found that you can also add footnotes (see discussion here http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/markdown_document_format.html ) I'm beginning to think (R)Markdown is the format to rule them all.

Answer (score 47):

Another easy way to do this is to just use HTML tags. Adding `<br>` will give a single line break and I've used that when, for whatever reason, using the  (two-space indentation) is ignored.

Comment: Another fix is putting a backslash `\\` just in front of the newline, resulting in a blank line in the html. I also find that two-spaces followed by newline does not work.

Answer (score 47):

To create vertical space (Markdown to PDF), I use `&nbsp;`

This command works like `\vspace{12pt}` for latex.

Comment: Fantastic! This works beautifully. Thank you kindly.

Comment: No downvote or anything, just clarify that works for pdf but not html

Comment: what is equivalent of `\vspace{-12pt}`?

Answer (score 19):

You can also use inline LaTeX to create a 1-inch vertical space like this:

```
text text text

$$\\[1in]$$

text text text
```

Note that you have to leave a blank line before and after the `$$\\[1in]$$`

Comment: awesome . . . fyi, this does work in HTML

Comment: It surely does. It creates a math box full of nothing, but taking up 1 inch of vertical space

Comment: [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\\[1in]', rendering as TeX:
  \\[1in]
    ^
  unexpected "["
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace

Comment: genius level - the cleanest and simplest solution I've seen yet. No need to learn css, etc...

Answer (score 0):

`\pagebreak` can be used the whitespace of an RMarkdown document. Alternatively, `cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")` can be used within an R script.

Example:

Here I insert some text into an RMarkdown document.

```
  cat("  \n## And here I am demonstrating text within an R script. \n")
  
  cat("  \n### More text. \n")

  cat("  \n### Add page break... \n")
  
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")

  cat("  \n### Item on new page. \n")
```